# How to change the format of the string representation of a pandas datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index. I want to change the string representation of the index to remove seconds from the end of timestamp. I'm aware I can change the datetime index into strings of the desired format using strftime, but then it will no longer be a datetime index. E.g.

```
df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

I'm aware that a pandas datetime index has a method called format, which accepts a "formatter" as an input, but I can't locate any information in the documentation as to what a formatter should look like. I've tried using strftime style strings, but it gives an error. E.g.

```
df.index.format(formatter='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you care so much about the formatting? I guess that would require writing your own `__str__` method and monkey-patching it - I would not want to do this ;-)

Comment: Frequently I end up with timestamps displayed to the millisecond, which is absurd when my data is hourly. I want to trim off the surplus representation but maintain a datetime index. Another use case would be to effectively "round down" the timestamps to the nearest timeslot by discarding minutes or seconds from the timestamp, and then dropping duplicates to keep only the first record in each slot i.e. I don't want to resample by data, I just want to keep the first record in each time bin.

Comment: hm ok, what about using [pandas.Series.dt.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) with a suitable frequency?

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works for my rounding use case, much appreciated. I'm still left with the display issue where it shows my hourly values to millisecond level precision, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: internally, it's handled with nanosecond precision anyway... but better have information you don't use than miss information you don't have.